# What does "reimplementations of deep learning algorithms which replicate performance from the papers" mean?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, papers, research, implementation

In the [OpenAI's Machine Learning Fellow position](https://startup.jobs/3993-machine-learning-fellow-at-openai), it is written

> We look for candidates with one or more of the following credentials:
>
> - ...
> - Open-source reimplementations of deep learning algorithms which replicate performance from the papers

What exactly do they mean by this? Do they want us to implement the algorithms exactly as described in the papers (i.e. with the same hyper-parameters, weights, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accompanying ML/AI (and computer science, in general) papers with the relevant code is much desirable, both for reproducibility of the paper results as well as for faster integration of these results into applications.

Some researchers do so by themselves; but this has lately become also a community job, where a third, independent individual or team, not affiliated with the paper author(s), offers a code implementation starting from the paper.

A good, very recent case is the reproduction of the [World Models](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.10122) paper ([blog post](https://medium.com/applied-data-science/how-to-build-your-own-world-model-using-python-and-keras-64fb388ba459), [Github repo](https://github.com/AppliedDataSciencePartners/WorldModels)). Many of the implementations available at [Papers with Code](https://paperswithcode.com) are indeed provided by the community.

A great write-up of such an effort, containing many lessons learned, made big raves recently: [Lessons Learned Reproducing a Deep Reinforcement Learning Paper](http://amid.fish/reproducing-deep-rl).

Understandably, individuals that have such efforts in their CV are a good recruiting option...

Comment: In addition to this, do you find the stated "statement (Open-source reimplementations of deep learning algorithms)" demanding for reimplementation of some Machine Learning Model's based on some paper or the reimplementation of the very learning techniques themselves (e.g. back-propagation)?

Comment: @ShoaibAnwar probably the former; a re-implementation of BP is not of any particular value, apart from a purely educational perspective, and such efforts abound

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this:

- **"reimplementations of deep learning algorithms"**
  He is asking that they are looking for people who have made and completed an AI that perform similarly or exactly as those given in papers (IDK which papers)
- **"Open-source"** The Fellow wants to be able to see the source code of the project.